# GoJS Diagram - Get the object which was Double Clicked

Tags: javascript, events, gojs

I am using the GOJS (http://www.gojs.net/latest/index.html) and have a diagram with some nodes on it which have their own data model structure.

I am attaching a "ObjectDoubleClicked" event like so:

```
    Diagram.addDiagramListener("ObjectDoubleClicked", function (e)
    {
        // Do something
    });
```

The event fires just fine but I am unable to get the subject (bring the node) of the event. The e.subject stays undefined.

As I have multiple node types which would be dropped on the diagram , I need to manage them.

What is the best way for me to get the node which was double clicked?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cj6andrL/3/) with a basic example of what you are asking.

### HTML

```
<div id="myDiagram"></div>
```

### CSS

```
#myDiagram{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

You must assign a width and height to the Diagram or it will not show up.

### JavaScript

```
var $ = go.GraphObject.make;
var myDiagram = $(go.Diagram, "myDiagram", {
    initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center,
    "undoManager.isEnabled": true
});

myDiagram.addDiagramListener("ObjectDoubleClicked", function (ev) {
    console.log(ev.subject); //Successfully logs the node you clicked.
    console.log(ev.subject.ie); //Successfully logs the node's name.
});

//(...) I've skipped the key adding, because it's not necessary to understand this code.
```

Most of the code is taken from the [**go.js Diagram class**](http://www.gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Diagram.html) and [**go.js DiagramEvent class**](http://www.gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/DiagramEvent.html) documentation.

Hope it's what you wanted!